# MySQL index suggestion

Tags: mysql, indexing

```
select distinct g4_airport.id              as g4airportidentifier,
            airport.id                 as airportidentifier,
            airport.iata_code          as airportiata,
            airport.ident              as airporticao,
            airport.local_code         as airportfaa,
            airport.lastupdated        as lastupdated,
            g4_airport.last_updated    as lastupdatedg4,
            airport.name               as airportname,
            airport.municipality       as cityname,
            airport.latitude           as latitude,
            airport.longitude          as longitude,
            airport.region_iso         as regioniso,
            airport.country_iso        as countryiso,
            airport.timezone           as timezonename,
            g4_airport.is_fuel         as isfuel,
            g4_airport.use_tsa_scanner as isscanner,
            g4_airport.is_station      as isstation,
            g4_airport.is_charter      as ischarter,
            g4_airport.min_connection  as minconnectiontime,
            g4_airport.max_connection  as maxconnectiontime,
            g4_airport.min_turn        as minturn,
            g4_airport.rp_turn         as rpturn,
            g4_airport.acars_active    as isacarsactive,
            g4_airport.code_type       as codetype
from   airports.g4_airport
   join airports.airport
     on g4_airport.code = case g4_airport.code_type
                            when 'iata' then airport.iata_code
                            when 'faa' then airport.local_code
                            when 'icao' then airport.ident
                          end
where  airport.country_iso = 'us'
order  by airport.iata_code;
```

I have situation that the query is running 11 seconds while I tried to create index on all the columns mentioned in case and join. Still mysql is not picking up the index. Please help and advice.

Comment: What indices do you have so far?

Comment: update your question and add your tables schema  ..

Comment: MySQL can't use a index because of the CASE statement.. "update your question and add your tables schema " Also add in example data and expected results to extend @scaisEdge' s comment .. Also a DISTINCT is know to slow down execution, Only problem is you can't index a DISTINCT that uses multiple tables so a filesort (quicksort algorithm) is always needed

Answer (score 0):

MySQL cannot use an index for the join.

You could use a union over three joins (one each for iata, faa, icao).

Comment: MySQL cannot use indexes on JOINS? really? MySQL can't use a index on the topic starters join because of the CASE statement.

Answer (score 0):

**Focusing on...**

```
SELECT  ...
    from  g4_airport AS g4
    join     airport AS a
         ON g4.code = case g4.code_type
             when 'iata' then a.iata_code
             when 'faa'  then a.local_code
             when 'icao' then a.ident   end
    where  a.country_iso = 'us'
    order by  a.iata_code;
```

Please try these and provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and timing.

Toss the `DISTINCT`, I don't think it is needed, at least not in my Thoughts 2,3.

**Thought #1:**  `INDEX(country_iso, iata_code)`

**Thought #2:**

```
( SELECT  ...
    from  g4_airport AS g4
    join     airport AS a
         ON g4.code_type = 'iata'
        AND g4.code = a.iata_code
    where  a.country_iso = 'us'
    order by  a.iata_code;
) UNION ALL
( SELECT  ...
    from  g4_airport AS g4
    join     airport AS a
         ON g4.code_type = 'faa'
        AND g4.code = a.local_code
    where  a.country_iso = 'us'
)
) UNION ALL
( SELECT  ...
    ...  icao...ident
)    
ORDER BY  a.iata_code;

airport:     INDEX(country_iso)   -- although it may not be used
g4_airport:  INDEX(code_type, code)  -- for each `JOIN`
```

**Thought #3:**

First get the ids, then look up the details

```
SELECT a..., g4...        -- the various columns desired
    FROM
    (      -- start of UNION
        ( SELECT  a.id AS aid, g4.id AS g4id   -- only the PKs
            from  g4_airport AS g4
            join     airport AS a
                 ON g4.code_type = 'iata'
                AND g4.code = a.iata_code
            where  a.country_iso = 'us'
            order by  a.iata_code;
        ) UNION ALL
        ( SELECT  a.id AS aid, g4.id AS g4id
            from  g4_airport AS g4
            join     airport AS a
                 ON g4.code_type = 'faa'
                AND g4.code = a.local_code
            where  a.country_iso = 'us'
        )
        ) UNION ALL
        ( SELECT  ...
            ...  icao...ident
        )
    ) AS u       -- end of the UNION
    JOIN    airport AS a  WHERE  a.id = u.aid
    JOIN ga_airport AS g4 WHERE g4.id = u.g4id
    ORDER BY  u.iata_code;

airport:     INDEX(country_iso)   -- although it may not be used
g4_airport:  INDEX(code_type, code)  -- for each `JOIN`
```

(I assume `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` if each table.)

I do not know if Thought #3 will be any faster than #2.

(Thoughts #2,3 may have the tables backwards.)